# Make updating a property in one class trigger the setter for a property of that type in another class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, inotifypropertychanged

I am using MVVM with Galasoft MVVMLight libraries.

I have two models; each has a boolean property and different properties of the same type.

```
public class Model1 : ObservableObject
{
    public EnumPair<YesNoInherit> Model1Property
    {
        get { return _model1Property; }
        set
        {
            _model1Property = value;
            Updated = true
            RaisePropertyChanged("Model1Property");
        }
    }

    public bool Updated
    {
        get { return _updated; }
        set
        {
            _updated = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Updated");
        }
    }
}

public class Model2 : ObservableObject
{
    public EnumPair<YesNoInherit> Model2Property
    {
        get { return _model2Property; }
        set
        {
            _model2Property = value;
            Updated = true
            RaisePropertyChanged("Model2Property");
        }
    }

    public bool Updated
    {
        get { return _updated; }
        set
        {
            _updated = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Updated");
        }
    }
}
```

The type YesNoInherit is an enum having values No, Yes, and Inherit.

Here is the EnumPair class.

```
public class EnumPair<T> : ObservableObject where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    public T EnumValue
    {
        get { return _enumValue; }
        set
        {
            if (Type.Equals(value, _enumValue) == false)
            {
                _enumValue = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string SourceName
    {
        get { return _sourceName; }
        set
        {
            _sourceName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

In my view, I am trying to use a ComboBox to let the user select one of the three enum values, and, in some cases, display custom text.  The resource "enumComboBoxTemplate" allows the ComboBox drop-down to show enum descriptions.  The converter "inheritanceEnum2Desc" is where the custom text would be applied.  "object1" is an instance of "Model1".

```
<ComboBox ItemTemplate=ItemTemplate="{StaticResource enumComboBoxTemplate}"
          EnumSource="enums:YesNoInherit">
    <ComboBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource inheritanceEnum2Desc}">
            <Binding Path="object1.EnumValue"/>
            <Binding Path="object1.SourceName"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ComboBox.Text>
</ComboBox>
```

"Model2" would be used in future programming employing similar functionality, but with different data.

When I change the selection in the ComboBox, I want to change the value of "Updated" (from false to true) so I can enable a button in the view.  This appears to require that the EnumPair class somehow make the program execute the setter for Model1Property.  Since the two model classes have properties of type EnumPair, I don't believe I can add any code in EnumPair specific to either model class.

How can I accomplish this?  I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: ""Model2" would be used in future programming employing similar functionality, but with different data." This sounds like you shouldn't create two separate classes but rather creating two separate instances instead. However I don't really get your point. This sounds like you need a ViewModelLocator to access your static ViewModels. Please describe your issue further.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have two options: either use some kind of message-bus to update the other model (Prism has `EventAggregator`, not sure about MVVMLight) or make both model instances forward their properties to a common data source that notifies all of its users when a property changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to easily change from one class to another in the future without rewriting all of your code, you need to create an Interface that defines all of the things that the two models have in common, and both model classes need to implement the interface.  You could call the interface IModel1

So, instead of having a "Model1" in your viewmodel, you would have an "IModel1" in your viewmodel instead.  You could pass in the same object you are passing in now, which is of type Model1, because it implements the IModel1 interface.  When you are ready to switch, pass in a Model2 instead, and it will work without having to rewrite anything in your view or viewmodel.  Your setters can be completely different - as long as both models have all of the methods and properties that are required by the interface, you will be OK.

Alternately, if Model2 is exactly like Model1 except that it has "extra stuff," you can make Model2 a derived class which derives from Model1.

Google searching either of those terms should point you toward a good tutorial.

Comment: if you mean change from Model1 to Model2, I'm not doing that. Model1 is in one view, while Model2 is in another view.  Model1 & Model2 aren't related, other than each class having an EnumPair property.  In one app (App1), its combobox is bound to object1.Model1Property.EnumValue; in another app (App2), its combobox is bound to object2.Model2Property.EnumValue. If in App1 I change the combobox's value, the code in the setter for Model1Property should run; if in App2 I change the combobox's value, the code in the setter for Model2Property should run. Does this change your answer?

Comment: Yes, it does change the answer.  In Model1 and Model2, just use different code in your setter (whether the EnumPair properties have the same name and same Type or not.)  Why would you need to use the same logic in both model classes just because they both have the same type of property?  That is like saying that Window1 and Window2 have to have the same title just because they both have a "Title" property, or that Button1 and Button2 need the same OnClick behavior just because both buttons have an "OnClick" event.  What is the actual problem that you are running into?